# Debian 12: Why python3-scipy package requires libbost-dev?

Tags: debian

I have noticed that on Debian 12 package python3-scipy depends on libboost-dev:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libboost-dev libboost1.74-dev liblbfgsb0 libopenblas-dev
  libopenblas-pthread-dev libopenblas0 libxsimd-dev python3-beniget
  python3-gast python3-ply python3-pythran
```

Is it a bug or feature? It seems to me that *scipy* shouldn't require C++ header files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s a feature — [the `python3-scipy` package](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/python3-scipy) now depends on [Pythran](https://github.com/serge-sans-paille/pythran), the compiler for numeric kernels, and that relies on Boost.